# Lambert Function as a solution

Tags: special-functions

The solution to the equation

$$Xe^X=K$$

is given by

$$X=W(K)$$

where $W$ is the Lambert function.

Is it possible to adapt this such that we can find a solution for

$$\frac{1-e^X}{X}=K?$$

Comment: Mathematica gives $X=\frac{1-K W\left(\frac{e^{1/K}}{K}\right)}{K}$.

Comment: @user1337 Which version are you using? Mine tells me it is unsolvable.

Comment: I meant Wolfram Alpha, sorry.

Comment: Write $\text{Solve}[\dfrac{1-e^x}x==k,x]$, and tell me is it still fails to return a result in terms of Lambert's W function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 
$$ \tag+\frac{1-e^X}X = K \iff 1-KX = e^X \iff (1-KX)\cdot e^{-X} = 1$$
We want to have something of the form $Ye^Y$ to apply $W$, hence we write 
$$ e^{-X} = e^{-\frac{KX}K} = \frac{e^{\frac 1K - \frac{KX}K}}{e^{1/K}}  = \frac{e^{\frac{1-KX}K}}{e^{1/K}} $$
So, we divide $(+)$ by $K$ to get 
$$ \frac{1-KX}{K} \cdot e^{\frac{1-KX}K} = \frac{e^{1/K}}K \iff \frac{1-KX}K = W\left(\frac{e^{1/K}}K\right) \iff X = \frac 1K-W\left(\frac{e^{1/K}}K\right) $$

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by user1337 in the comments is correct. To derive it rewrite your equation

$$ \frac{1-e^{X}}{X} = K$$

to

$$ \frac{1-KX}{K}e^{\frac{1-XK}{K}} = \frac{e^{\frac{1}{K}}}{K}$$

This is now on the form $W(Z) e^{W(Z)} = Z$ with $W(Z) = \frac{1-XK}{K}$ and $Z =  \frac{e^{\frac{1}{K}}}{K}$.

Answer (score 0):

The solution using variation of parameters is 
$$
x=\frac{1}{K}-\operatorname{W}\left( \frac{{{e}^{\frac{1}{K}}}}{K}\right) 
$$