# Prove or disprove the validity of a statement and find all solutions

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

### Find all possible values of $x$ if
$$\sqrt[x]{\frac{2}{x-1}}=(x-1)^{(x-2)}$$

My attempt:

$$\frac{2}{x-1}=(x-1)^{(x-2)x}$$
$$\implies2=(x-1)^{(x^2-2x+1)}$$
$$\implies2=(x-1)^{(x-1)^2}$$ Let $x-1=a$

Therefore $$2=a^{a^2}$$ By observation, $a=\pm\sqrt2$ satisfies the equation.  $\implies$
$$x=\sqrt2+1 \:\:\textrm{or} \:\:x=1-\sqrt2$$
My doubts:

$1.$ Is an expression like
$$\sqrt[{\sqrt2+1}]{y}$$ or $$\sqrt[{-\sqrt2+1}]{y}$$ even valid$?$

$2.$ How do we find all solutions to the equation $$2=a^{a^2}$$ assuming that the domain of $a$ is both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that to determine real solutions you should also check that we only have one solution, in this case since for $1<x\le 2$ we have $f(x)=(x-1)^{(x-1)^2}\le 1$ and $f(x)$ is continuous and increasing for $x>2$, by [IVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), we can claim that $x=\sqrt2+1$ is the unique real solution for $x>1$.

By inspection we find that also the symmetric value $x=-\sqrt2+1$ is also a solution.

This kind of expression $\sqrt[{\sqrt2+1}]{y}$ and $\sqrt[{-\sqrt2+1}]{y}$ are valid and equivalent to

$$\sqrt[{\sqrt2+1}]{y}={y}^{\frac1{\sqrt2+1}}$$
$$\sqrt[{-\sqrt2+1}]{y}={y}^{\frac1{-\sqrt2+1}}=\frac1{{y}^{\frac1{\sqrt2-1}}}$$

with $y>0$ if we are dealing with real expressions.

For a general solution we can use [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) as discusse for example here

- [Lambert Function as a solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859108/lambert-function-as-a-solution)

Comment: Using function we need to restrict to $x-1>0$, then by inspection we can also find the negative solution.